# Python sad/happy face machine learning (Get rid of text)

Tags: python-2.7

I could use a little advice on how to make an for loop / if statement, so i can get rid of some unnecessary text in a file.

I got a txt file, which is large 153mb. I know how to open it in python, but I am still not the best taking stuff (text i don't need) out of it.

I posted an example of the txt file u can see under here:

```
@xirwinshemmo thanks for the follow :)
hii... if u want to make a new friend just add me on facebook! :) xx      https:\/\/t.co\/RCYFVrmdDG
Just wanna say if you ever feel lonely or sad or bored, just come and talk to me. I'm   free anytime :)
I hope she not a spy for someone. I hope she real on neautral side. Because just her who   i trust. :-)
@dessdim @Bureemi not always but sometimes maybe :)
\u201c@EmilyKathryn_17: Funny how you get what you want and pray for when you want the    same thing God wants.  :) #newheart #newdesires\u201d
@PhilKomarny Thank you :) can you follow me on Twitter so I can DM you?
RT @emrekavcoglu: @Usher dj got us a fallin in love and yeah earth number one m\u00fcsic    listen thank you king :-)
@
```

What i want is to get rid of all @ + names, like the first one:

```
@xirwinshemmo
```

and only have the text "thanks for the follow :)"

there is also links that i can't use like:

```
https:\/\/t.co\/RCYFVrmdDG
```

also want to remove this.

Hope some can maybe help a bit.

Comment: what code have you written and tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm going to assume that you are reading the file line by line. So we can first split each line into individual words (strings):

```
for line in infile:
    words = line.split() # splits long string into array of single words
```

Then, I would loop over these words (still part of the above for loop)

```
i = 0
for i in xrange(len(words)):
    if words[i].startswith('@'):
        print words[i+1:len(words)]
```

This code will print only the words that come after the user name (@abc).

To remove the http links, you can use this `if` statement

```
if not words[i].startswith('http'):
```